# cucumber - generating wrong missing steps

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

I am using cucumber and TestNG in my automation code

.feature file

```
Scenario Outline: Enter valid Location Setup 
    When : I enter the Restaurant ID as “<setup_RestaurantID>“ 
    Examples: 
        | setup_StoreID | setup_RestaurantID | 
        | test          | 1234               |
```

When I run automation script it is generating blow missing step

```
@When("^: I enter the Restaurant ID as “(\\d+)“$")
public void i_enter_the_Restaurant_ID_as(int arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

But cucumber supposed to generate missing step as follow

```
@When("^: I enter the Restaurant ID as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_enter_the_Restaurant_ID_as(String arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Other settings:

monochrome = true

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
<version>1.2.5</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
<version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
<version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Can you help me to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Replaced inverted commas(“) with double quotes(") for parameter.

After spending couple of hours observed that the parameter surrounded with double inverted commas instead double quotes. Actually I had received feature file from BA and he has used apple notes(smart quotes enabled) to write .feature file which  converts double quote to inverted comma.

```
When : I enter the Restaurant ID as "<setup_RestaurantID>"
```